# Openlayers-3 fitExtent capture replay not working

Tags: openlayers-3

I'm creating a 'bookmarking' feature on my map, recording the extent of the current view via `ol.View.calculateExtent()`.  Once I've grabbed this extent I persist it (no loss of precision, in 'EPSG:900913').

Problem now is if I feed this extent into `ol.View.fitExtent()` I don't get exactly the same view, I get a slightly 'zoomed out' one.

The coordinates are exactly the same, the map size (`ol.Map.getSize()`) even the resolution (`ol.View().getResolution()`) but each time my recorded 'view' when I call it is further out than the recorded one.

Any ideas how I can exactly record the current 'view' and replay it accurately?Is this rounding?  Should I not be using fitExtent?

N.B. This doesn't ALWAYS' happen!  At high zooms it can sometimes accurately record and return me to the same view - resolutions at 2.388657133911758,  1.194328566955879 and 305.748113140705, when recorded, do not seem to exhibit this behaviour.

Comment: Which version of OpenLayers are you using? I recently moved from 3.1.1 to 3.7 and found that `fitExtent()` seems to be deprecated.

Comment: A modified 3.5.0 - `fitExtent()` is still in that version.  I cannot upgrade just yet as the modifications would need to be ported.  Looking at the changelog, the change to `fit()` just consolidated the function call, it didn't change the way it works.

Answer (score 0):

It has been replaced by `ol.View.fit` in [v3.7.0](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/releases/tag/v3.7.0):

> Replace ol.View.fitExtent() and ol.View.fitGeometry() with
>   ol.View.fit() ... This combines two previously distinct functions into
>   one more flexible call which takes either a geometry or an extent.